# Combine expression with sprintf result in R for ggplot/plot-labeling

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, expression, character

I would like to use `expression` in combination with a `sprintf`-result for labeling in `ggplot2` or `plot`.

So I tried (meaningless example, just for illustrating the problem):

```
require(ggplot2)
test <- 2
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = expression(""<=sprintf(paste0("%.", test, "f"), pi)))
```

Obviously, that doesn't work (just evaluating `<=` and `pi`), even though both separate elements does. Is there a possibility to rewrite the expression, so it will work with the combination? I already tried to include `~` or `eval(parse(text = ...))` but these do not work either. Last: it is essential to integrate the `test`-object into `sprintf` for me.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
So here is a better example. Thought I made the other one as minimal as possible, but obviously than it wasn't specific enough. Sorry for that. Hopefully, it is possible to understand my question know. Thank you!

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

# data
ids <- factor(c("1.1", "2.1", "1.2", "2.2", "1.3", "2.3"))
values <- data.frame(id = ids,
                 value = c(3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.15, 3.5))
positions <- data.frame(id = rep(ids, each = 4),
                    x = c(2, 1, 1.1, 2.2, 1, 0, 0.3, 1.1, 2.2, 1.1, 1.2, 2.5, 1.1, 0.3,
                          0.5, 1.2, 2.5, 1.2, 1.3, 2.7, 1.2, 0.5, 0.6, 1.3),
                    y = c(-0.5, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 2.1, 1.7, 1, 1.5,
                          2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 2.1, 3.2, 2.8, 2.1, 2.2, 3.3, 3.2))
datapoly <- merge(values, positions, by = c("id"))

# plot preperation (for many ggplots is especially decimals output of a function)
decimals <- 2
lim_min <- 3.1
lim_max <- 3.4
breaks <- seq(lim_min, lim_max, (lim_max - lim_min)/4)
labels <- c(paste0("<", sprintf(paste0("%.", decimals, "f"), breaks[1])),
        sprintf(paste0("%.", decimals, "f"), breaks[2]),
        sprintf(paste0("%.", decimals, "f"), breaks[3]),
        sprintf(paste0("%.", decimals, "f"), breaks[4]),
        paste0(">", sprintf(paste0("%.", decimals, "f"), breaks[5])))

# plot
ggplot(datapoly, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = value, group = id)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(3.1, 3.4),
                  low = "green", high = "orange",
                  breaks = breaks,
                  labels = labels,
                  oob = squish)
```

Now the axis ticks labels are `"<3.10" "3.17"  "3.25"  "3.33"  ">3.40"` and I would like to have `"<=3.10" "3.17"  "3.25"  "3.33"  ">=3.40"`, but instead of `>=` and `<=` with the math symbols like [here](http://www.symbols.com/symbol/greater-than-or-equal-to) and [here](http://www.symbols.com/symbol/less-than-or-equal-to)

Comment: what's the expression you're trying to display? And why is sprintf essential? (as opposed to bquote or substitute, for instance)?

Comment: The expression I want to display is the above one. I thought `sprintf` is essential for me, because I use it originally in the labels for the axis ticks and these should have all the same number of decimals, e.g. `c("0.00", "0.01",...)`. The number of decimals is different for many ggplots and `test` is the optional variable to identify the required number of decimals. I used this as a way to "generalize" my plots, because it's not possible to have a look at each one. Maybe I should add a better example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found a solution by myself after the hint of baptiste to `substitute`. Changing

```
labels <- c(substitute(""<=a, list(a =sprintf(paste0("%.", decimals, "f"), breaks[1]))),
            sprintf(paste0("%.", decimals, "f"), breaks[2]),
            sprintf(paste0("%.", decimals, "f"), breaks[3]),
            sprintf(paste0("%.", decimals, "f"), breaks[4]),
            substitute("">=a, list(a =sprintf(paste0("%.", decimals, "f"), breaks[5]))))
```

in the above latter example, results in what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you looking for?

```
out <- sprintf(paste0("%.", test, "f"), pi)
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = paste(expression("<="), out))
```

[image]

Comment: But then I loose the math symbol for "smaller or equal than"?

Comment: what do you mean by losing the math? `scale_x_continuous(name)` argument only provide the axis label.

Please edit the question to show what is it that you wanted to achieve.

Comment: I meant, I would like to have math symbols like [this](http://www.symbols.com/symbol/less-than-or-equal-to) and [this one](http://www.symbols.com/symbol/greater-than-or-equal-to) instead of `<=` and `>=`. I edited the question and add a better example. Sorry for that.